# Outlook 2013 invite not showing embeded attachment - text/calendar;method=REQUEST

Tags: calendar, outlook, smtp, tcl, mime

Im creating an email with a text/calendar type. It has 3 alternate views: text, html, and the last is the meeting invite or .ics. I am not attaching the ics, but rather placing it in the content of the third view.

When I send it, outlook 2013 correctly receives the invite and shows the Accept/Tentative/Decline buttons at the top of the message.

However when I try to embed an attachment into the event/meeting it simply doesnt grab it.

If I send the ics as an attachment, it will have them embeded attachment, however users will have to click on the .ics file instead of getting the inline Accept/Tentative/Decline.

Im generating this in a scripting language called tcl. Im using the mime and smtp libraries. I've been referencing tcl, c#, php, and java implementations, and it doesnt seem that anyone has documented this exact scenario.

I can post my code if needed, however its pretty irrelevant. What is relevant is the mime message being built.

#### How do I embed an attachment into an event/calendar item?

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <30261.1428705114.6@cleaf1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: multipart/related;
              boundary="----- =_D0iKdgI+3r1IL2tYlWQ+zA=="

------- =_D0iKdgI+3r1IL2tYlWQ+zA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <30261.1428705114.4@cleaf1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
              boundary="----- =_6M80yPWZSMRuPfyOccOhUw=="

------- =_6M80yPWZSMRuPfyOccOhUw==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <30261.1428705114.1@cleaf1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: text/plain;
              charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Plain Text
Line2
------- =_6M80yPWZSMRuPfyOccOhUw==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <30261.1428705114.2@cleaf1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: text/html;
              charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

html
line2
------- =_6M80yPWZSMRuPfyOccOhUw==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <30261.1428705114.3@cleaf1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: text/calendar;method=request; charset="utf-8";
              charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=No Reply:mailto:NoReply@mydomain.org
ATTENDEE;CN='Todd';ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=FALSE:MAILTO:thorst2@mydomain.org
DTSTART:20150411T120000Z
DTEND:20150411T140000Z
LOCATION:
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:a526f058fba04a4067966986ce365080
DTSTAMP:20150410T223154Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20150410T223154Z
DESCRIPTION:Test Description
SUMMARY:Test Title
ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=DOC_FR_MD_in.20150317_154551
 .idx.gz:H4sICE9oCFUCA0RPQ19GUl9NRF9pbi4yMDE1MDMxN18xNTQ1NTEuaWR4AO2Wz47bIB
 DG732KeQTAhjhHYnBi1f8Wxqvd00pVL71sT5UqWX73QtbZQpJVWm9UbRVzwh/MxzBj/+RhqEsF
 w6DaWpYNEBhh2PUbNwE/bfoaGCMs9c8wjk6yJo9ChnEKGcbXED99GfsQfOw0KInSr9u2N7nO26
 YB1eZPhXmqFcwazqw15faqhkpb3FuR42POr2BZa6ApE4KQNedO6UzptuMjcMqId3T3LmqMw6y8
 9xmjfkD49vzl+4/nr/tzisLqcGuUW6WbLe6AUk75QSsqubVAfhKSEcK8M0rUL33cmrbv/rZXDx
 XizmipgoW5xTQaTant0dU/l507BHxtequNq8O9NmoD7JCyy/ikxi75qMpe8y5e5IJknE1i258R
 7/LenHreYYunqkvo1MBie8ZAmjwW1QblptLvLd3/PnyXdZfvpDnqvTKl63WOFYgskP1rsMdDsH
 n8NPwBmlIqErqg6QKaKEnF+jpocvDJkrfRJIhIbxVNhyqHaIp4dUBTJM5BU2SwoOljosl9Y2y9
 oOkSmmhGVtdBE1utpv+is2ji7qybRdNU5QhNIa9e0RSKs9AUGixo+qBoYpTzBU2X0JQmnF4HTW
 mSrNO30ZSsMnGzaJqqHKMp4NVvNAXiPDQFBgua/j2afgGbA8R2bBIAAA==
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:FREE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:TRUE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
------- =_6M80yPWZSMRuPfyOccOhUw==--

------- =_D0iKdgI+3r1IL2tYlWQ+zA==--
```

This is generated by the mime library, and as i said if i send as an attachment it works. It just doesnt work when using text/calendar;method=REQUEST and placing it in an alternative view

I suspect its with my mime message (email) structure or it headers

#### Update 1:

Here is my new code, per recommendation to have a flatter structure. With or without the content type having charset and with or without content transfer, didnt seem to make a difference. The email still is received, and presents the Accept/Tentative/Decline buttons, but no attachment:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <12516.1428711300.1@cleaf1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: text/calendar;
              charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150411T120000Z
DTEND:20150411T140000Z
SEQUENCE:0
UID:54690bbc05124b2e7c4ad5d480025278
DTSTAMP:20150411T001500Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20150411T001500Z
DESCRIPTION:Test appointment body
SUMMARY:Test Title
ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=DOC_FR_MD_in.20150317_154551
    .idx.gz:H4sICE9oCFUCA0RPQ19GUl9NRF9pbi4yMDE1MDMxN18xNTQ1NTEuaWR4AO2Wz47bIB
    DG732KeQTAhjhHYnBi1f8Wxqvd00pVL71sT5UqWX73QtbZQpJVWm9UbRVzwh/MxzBj/+RhqEsF
    w6DaWpYNEBhh2PUbNwE/bfoaGCMs9c8wjk6yJo9ChnEKGcbXED99GfsQfOw0KInSr9u2N7nO26
    YB1eZPhXmqFcwazqw15faqhkpb3FuR42POr2BZa6ApE4KQNedO6UzptuMjcMqId3T3LmqMw6y8
    9xmjfkD49vzl+4/nr/tzisLqcGuUW6WbLe6AUk75QSsqubVAfhKSEcK8M0rUL33cmrbv/rZXDx
    XizmipgoW5xTQaTant0dU/l507BHxtequNq8O9NmoD7JCyy/ikxi75qMpe8y5e5IJknE1i258R
    7/LenHreYYunqkvo1MBie8ZAmjwW1QblptLvLd3/PnyXdZfvpDnqvTKl63WOFYgskP1rsMdDsH
    n8NPwBmlIqErqg6QKaKEnF+jpocvDJkrfRJIhIbxVNhyqHaIp4dUBTJM5BU2SwoOljosl9Y2y9
    oOkSmmhGVtdBE1utpv+is2ji7qybRdNU5QhNIa9e0RSKs9AUGixo+qBoYpTzBU2X0JQmnF4HTW
    mSrNO30ZSsMnGzaJqqHKMp4NVvNAXiPDQFBgua/j2afgGbA8R2bBIAAA==
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

#### Update #2 (Solution)

I marked the reply as the answer because it helped me find the solution. I've posted the solution in the question because I wanted to still give credit to @DmitryStreblechenko for helping me

Here is the tcl code:

```
    #######################################################
    # Initial Setup
    #######################################################
    #Import packages
    package require uuid
    package require mime                                               
    package require smtp

    #Set up basic appointment template
    set tmplICS "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:@start
DTEND:@end
SEQUENCE:0
UID:@uid
DTSTAMP:@created
LAST-MODIFIED:@created
DESCRIPTION:Test appointment body
SUMMARY:@summary
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR"

    #######################################################
    # Real Data
    #######################################################
    #Setup data for substitution
    set uuid [string map {- ""} [uuid::uuid generate]]

    #Now in utc
    set created [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ} -timezone :UTC]

    #Get todays date at 8, then add a day, then convert to utc
    set est [clock scan [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y%m%dT080000}]]
    set est [clock add $est 1 day]
    set utcStart [clock format $est -format {%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ} -timezone :UTC ]

    #Get todays date at 10, then add a day, then convert to utc
    set est [clock scan [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y%m%dT100000}]]
    set est [clock add $est 1 day]
    set utcEnd [clock format $est -format {%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ} -timezone :UTC ]

    #######################################################
    # Compile Data
    #######################################################
    #Fill in the template
    set mapper ""
    lappend mapper "@uid" $uuid
    lappend mapper "@start" $utcStart
    lappend mapper "@end" $utcEnd
    lappend mapper "@created" $created
    lappend mapper "@summary" "Test Title"
    set appointment [string map $mapper $tmplICS]

    #######################################################
    # Set up the bodies
    #######################################################
    #set up text and meeting request bodies
    set text [mime::initialize -canonical text/plain -string "hey"]
    set html [mime::initialize -canonical text/html -string "<b>hey</b>"]
    set token [mime::initialize -canonical "text/calendar;charset=\"utf-8\";method=REQUEST" -string $appointment]

    #Set up container
    set mimeBodies [mime::initialize -canonical multipart/alternative -parts [list $text $html $token]]


    #######################################################
    # Set up attachments
    #######################################################
    set att [mime::initialize -canonical "application/octet-stream; name=\"ReadMePlease.txt\"" \
                    -file "/qdxiprod/cis6.1/integrator/web/readme.txt" \
                    -header [list Content-Disposition "attachment"] ]
    set att1 [mime::initialize -canonical "application/hmtl; name=\"DOC_FR_MD.html\"" \
                    -file "/qdxiprod/cis6.1/integrator/testhtmlFile.html" \
                    -header [list Content-Disposition "attachment"] ]


    #######################################################
    # Finish the setup
    #######################################################
    #Bodies and attachments
    set mimeSum [mime::initialize -canonical multipart/mixed -parts [list $mimeBodies $att $att1]]

    #Output what it looks like
    echo [::mime::buildmessage $mimeSum]

    #The sum of the mime package looks like this
        #multipart/mixed
        #   multipart/alternative (holding the two forms of the body part)
        #       text/plain
        #       text/html
        #       text/calendar;method=REQUEST
        #   application/octet-stream (attachment #1)
        #   application/html (attachment #2)

    #Send email
    smtp::sendmessage $mimeSum -servers "smtp.mydomain.org" -header [list From "NoReply@mydomain.org"] -header [list To "myemail@mydomain.org"]

    #Destroy mime package
    mime::finalize $mimeSum
```

Here is the mime package:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <20418.1428888890.7@server1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
              boundary="----- =_FoyUc668JaIKjlKQbXOmqQ=="

------- =_FoyUc668JaIKjlKQbXOmqQ==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <20418.1428888890.4@server1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
              boundary="----- =_1trMjc6PUm3+p04m/SU8aA=="

------- =_1trMjc6PUm3+p04m/SU8aA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <20418.1428888890.1@server1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: text/plain

hey
------- =_1trMjc6PUm3+p04m/SU8aA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <20418.1428888890.2@server1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: text/html

hey
------- =_1trMjc6PUm3+p04m/SU8aA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-ID: <20418.1428888890.3@server1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: text/calendar;charset="utf-8";method=request

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150413T120000Z
DTEND:20150413T140000Z
SEQUENCE:0
UID:56b39b14ebb641ab7de716a62bed46aa
DTSTAMP:20150413T013450Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20150413T013450Z
DESCRIPTION:Test appointment body
SUMMARY:Test Title
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
------- =_1trMjc6PUm3+p04m/SU8aA==--

------- =_FoyUc668JaIKjlKQbXOmqQ==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-ID: <20418.1428888890.5@server1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="readmeplease.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MSAyNCBDdXN0b21pemUuZXhlLm1hbmlmZXN0

------- =_FoyUc668JaIKjlKQbXOmqQ==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-ID: <20418.1428888890.6@server1.mydomain.org>
Content-Type: application/hmtl; name="doc_fr_md.html"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MSAyNCBDdXN0b21pemUuZXhlLm1hbmlmZXN0

------- =_FoyUc668JaIKjlKQbXOmqQ==--
```

Comment: You have to create a `multipart/mixed` with 2 parts: a `multipart/alternative` and the attachment. The `multipart/alternative` should contain `text/html` and `text/plain` and maybe the ics part. Not sure about the last thing.

Comment: I think youre referring to just sending an .ics attachment, or possibly sending an invite request with the accept/tentative/decline buttons. Im not having issues there, my email works. What isnt working is embedded attachments inside of the event. See ATTACH segment.

Comment: I thought you want to send an E-Mail with an attachment and the .ics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook expects the meeting request MIME message to be a single part - text/calendar. Plain text and HTML must be in the VEVENT part (DESCRIPTION and X-ALT-DESC respectively). Attachments must also be added as ATTACH parts:

```
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Subject: Test
    Content-ID: <30261.1428705114.6@cleaf1.mydomain.org>
    Content-Type: text/calendar

    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    METHOD:PUBLISH
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME=test.txt:U3ViamVjdDoJRG1pdHJ
        5IE9uZSBvbiBPbmUNCkxvY2F0aW9uOglQYXVsJ3MgT2ZmaWNlDQoNClN0YXJ0OglUdWUgMTIvN
        C8yMDEyIDk6MzAgQU0NCkVuZDoJVHVlIDEyLzQvMjAxMiA5OjQ1IEFNDQoNClJlY3VycmVuY2U
        6CVdlZWtseQ0KUmVjdXJyZW5jZSBQYXR0ZXJuOglPY2N1cnMgZXZlcnkgVHVlc2RheSBmcm9tI
        Dk6MzAgQU0gdG8gOTo0NSBBTSBlZmZlY3RpdmUgMS8xNy8yMDEyLiAoVVRDLQ0KMDc6MDApIEF
        yaXpvbmENCg0KTWVldGluZyBTdGF0dXM6CUFjY2VwdGVkDQoNCk9yZ2FuaXplcjoJWmVpbWV0L
        CBQYXVsDQpSZXF1aXJlZCBBdHRlbmRlZXM6CVN0cmVibGVjaGVua28sIERtaXRyeQ0KDQoNCg=
        =
    DESCRIPTION:Test appointment body\n\n \n    
    X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
        N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
        rsion 14.02.5004.000">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
        rom text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calib
        ri">Test</FONT></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"><B> <FONT FACE="Calibri">appointm
        ent</FONT></B></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calibri"> body</FONT><
        /SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SP
        AN><SPAN LANG="en-us">&nbsp\;</SPAN></P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
```

Update. Outlook created the following MIME message when I sent a meeting invitation from Outlook (I removed some headers for clarity).

```
Return-Path: <xx@yy.com>
X-Original-To: xx@yy.com
Delivered-To: xx@yy.com
From: Dmitry Streblechenko < xx@yy.com>
To: "xx@yy.com" <xx@yy.com>
Subject: test with attachment
Thread-Topic: test with attachment
Thread-Index: AdB1Rk+XNqVZqNnURi+hrlBAI6rRFwAACvNA
Date: Sun, 12 Apr 2015 17:31:20 +0000
Message-ID: <CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80@CY1PR11MB0524.namprd11.prod.outlook.com>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_005_CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80CY1PR11MB0524namp_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80CY1PR11MB0524namp_"

--_000_CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80CY1PR11MB0524namp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Test body




--_000_CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80CY1PR11MB0524namp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<meta name=3D"Generator" content=3D"Microsoft Exchange Server">
<!-- converted from rtf -->
<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left:=
 #800000 2px solid; } --></style>
</head>
<body>
<font face=3D"Calibri" size=3D"2"><span style=3D"font-size:11pt;">
<div>Test <b>body</b></div>
<div><font face=3D"Times New Roman">&nbsp;</font></div>
<div><font face=3D"Times New Roman"> </font></div>
<div><font face=3D"Times New Roman">&nbsp;</font></div>
</span></font>
</body>
</html>

--_000_CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80CY1PR11MB0524namp_
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpNRVRIT0Q6UkVRVUVTVA0KUFJPRElEOk1pY3Jvc29mdCBFeGNoYW5n
ZSBTZXJ2ZXIgMjAxMA0KVkVSU0lPTjoyLjANCkJFR0lOOlZUSU1FWk9ORQ0KVFpJRDpVUyBNb3Vu
dGFpbiBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lDQpCRUdJTjpTVEFOREFSRA0KRFRTVEFSVDoxNjAxMDEwMVQwMDAw
MDANClRaT0ZGU0VURlJPTTotMDcwMA0KVFpPRkZTRVRUTzotMDcwMA0KRU5EOlNUQU5EQVJEDQpC
RUdJTjpEQVlMSUdIVA0KRFRTVEFSVDoxNjAxMDEwMVQwMDAwMDANClRaT0ZGU0VURlJPTTotMDcw
MA0KVFpPRkZTRVRUTzotMDcwMA0KRU5EOkRBWUxJR0hUDQpFTkQ6VlRJTUVaT05FDQpCRUdJTjpW
RVZFTlQNCk9SR0FOSVpFUjtDTj1EbWl0cnkgU3RyZWJsZWNoZW5rbzpNQUlMVE86ZG1pdHJ5QGRp
Z2l0YWwudGVjaG5vbG9neQ0KQVRURU5ERUU7Uk9MRT1SRVEtUEFSVElDSVBBTlQ7UEFSVFNUQVQ9
TkVFRFMtQUNUSU9OO1JTVlA9VFJVRTtDTj1kbWl0cnlAZGltDQogYXN0ci5jb206TUFJTFRPOmRt
aXRyeUBkaW1hc3RyLmNvbQ0KQVRURU5ERUU7Uk9MRT1SRVEtUEFSVElDSVBBTlQ7UEFSVFNUQVQ9
TkVFRFMtQUNUSU9OO1JTVlA9VFJVRTtDTj1kbWl0cnkuc3RyDQogZWJsZWNoZW5rb0BpbmZvci5j
b206TUFJTFRPOmRtaXRyeS5zdHJlYmxlY2hlbmtvQGluZm9yLmNvbQ0KQVRUQUNIOkNJRDo4QkMw
MEUzRTQ5NkRDNDQ5OTAwMkVENzQ4OEY4RTA4NEBuYW1wcmQxMS5wcm9kLm91dGxvb2suY29tDQpE
RVNDUklQVElPTjtMQU5HVUFHRT1lbi1VUzpUZXN0IGJvZHlcblxuXG5cbg0KVUlEOjA0MDAwMDAw
ODIwMEUwMDA3NEM1QjcxMDFBODJFMDA4MDAwMDAwMDAzMERGNTFCMDBCNzVEMDAxMDAwMDAwMDAw
MDAwMDAwDQogMDEwMDAwMDAwRTYxNzM0RjNCQkZFNEY0MjhDRTMyMTZEQ0E5RTVBNDYNClNVTU1B
Ulk7TEFOR1VBR0U9ZW4tVVM6dGVzdCB3aXRoIGF0dGFjaG1lbnQNCkRUU1RBUlQ7VFpJRD1VUyBN
b3VudGFpbiBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lOjIwMTUwNDE3VDExMDAwMA0KRFRFTkQ7VFpJRD1VUyBNb3Vu
dGFpbiBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lOjIwMTUwNDE3VDExMzAwMA0KQ0xBU1M6UFVCTElDDQpQUklPUklU
WTo1DQpEVFNUQU1QOjIwMTUwNDEyVDE3MzExN1oNClRSQU5TUDpPUEFRVUUNClNUQVRVUzpDT05G
SVJNRUQNClNFUVVFTkNFOjANCkxPQ0FUSU9OO0xBTkdVQUdFPWVuLVVTOg0KWC1NSUNST1NPRlQt
Q0RPLUFQUFQtU0VRVUVOQ0U6MA0KWC1NSUNST1NPRlQtQ0RPLU9XTkVSQVBQVElEOi02MjIwNDkz
MTMNClgtTUlDUk9TT0ZULUNETy1CVVNZU1RBVFVTOlRFTlRBVElWRQ0KWC1NSUNST1NPRlQtQ0RP
LUlOVEVOREVEU1RBVFVTOkJVU1kNClgtTUlDUk9TT0ZULUNETy1BTExEQVlFVkVOVDpGQUxTRQ0K
WC1NSUNST1NPRlQtQ0RPLUlNUE9SVEFOQ0U6MQ0KWC1NSUNST1NPRlQtQ0RPLUlOU1RUWVBFOjAN
ClgtTUlDUk9TT0ZULURJU0FMTE9XLUNPVU5URVI6RkFMU0UNCkJFR0lOOlZBTEFSTQ0KREVTQ1JJ
UFRJT046UkVNSU5ERVINClRSSUdHRVI7UkVMQVRFRD1TVEFSVDotUFQxNU0NCkFDVElPTjpESVNQ
TEFZDQpFTkQ6VkFMQVJNDQpFTkQ6VkVWRU5UDQpFTkQ6VkNBTEVOREFSDQo=

--_000_CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80CY1PR11MB0524namp_--

--_005_CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80CY1PR11MB0524namp_
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="manifest.rc"
Content-Description: manifest.rc
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="manifest.rc"; size=27;
    creation-date="Sat, 24 Apr 2010 05:10:59 GMT";
    modification-date="Tue, 30 Dec 2014 00:22:47 GMT"
Content-ID: <8BC00E3E496DC4499002ED7488F8E084@namprd11.prod.outlook.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MSAyNCBDdXN0b21pemUuZXhlLm1hbmlmZXN0

--_005_CY1PR11MB05242BD9613D40DB120FCCA8B7F80CY1PR11MB0524namp_--
```

Comment: I'd like it to be a request and not a publish. This also doesnt seem to be valid, because it doesnt have the start and end time, Im not sure if you left that out to be brief...I've updated my question with what i think your recommendations were, but its still not working.

Comment: That was just an example that shows DESCRIPTION, X-ALT-DESC and ATTACH parts.

Comment: ok, that's what i thought. I still cant get it to work- my lastest version is in the updated question.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong and Outlook itself sends an invitation with an attachment as multipart/mixed.

Comment: Did you read that, or do you have the mime output? I tried sending as mixed but couldnt get that working, Ill try again....

Comment: One layer didnt seem to make a difference. What blows my mind, is that if I send the exact same thing as an attachment it works fine.

Comment: I sent a meeting invitation with an attachment from Outlook then looked at PR_TRANSPORT_HEADERS property on the receiving side.

Comment: Looking at the full message source, Outlook created MIME above (see the updated answer).

Comment: by decoding the base64 i can see they didnt embed the attachment directly, but rather a pointer to the content id. I will try this. Thanks

Comment: Did you get this by changing the reg key for SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders? When i do that i see some of the mime, but not all that im expecting to see.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko How did you generate the mime message in your second code snippet?

Comment: Send an invitation to a Gmail address, then look at the message source there.